# Mongo : Matching Against ObjectId

Tags: javascript, mongodb

I'm trying to put together a javascript function to update a Mongo database. I thought the best field to match against for the query would b _id, but I am having an issue in trying to properly format the query with the required ObjectId().

I am passing the 12 digit hex number in to the function, but I'm not sure how I then format this to be an Object Id that Mongo will understand as such.

I've tried the following:

```
var thisId = new ObjectId(hexnumbergoeshere);

var thisId = "ObjectId(" + hexnumberinavargoeshere + ")";
```

Both of these throw an error.

I tried just giving the match clause just the hex number like this:

```
var myMatch = {_id:hexnumberinavargoeshere}
```

And, while that didn't produce an error, it didn't actually update the db.

Please could someone point me in the right direction as far as how I should format and pass the hex number so that it will work in my query.

**Edited to add more complete code:**

Here is the actual router function:

```
router.post('/edit', function(req,res){
    var theId = req.body.id;
    var idArray = theId.split("_");
    var thisField = idArray[1];
    var thisId = idArray[2];
    var theMatch = new ObjectId(thisId);
    var match = {_id:theMatch};
    var query = {$set:{thisField:req.body.value}};

    var MongoClient = mongodb.MongoClient;
    var url = 'mongodb://localhost:27017/gts';
    MongoClient.connect(url, function(err, db){
        if(err){
            console.log("Error connecting to the server",  err);
        }else{
            var collection = db.collection('events');
            collection.update(match,query, function(err, result){
                if(err){
                    console.log("Error inserting record", err);
                }else{
                    console.log("Update Success! " + result);
                    res.send(req.body.value);
                }
                db.close();
            });     
        }
    });
});
```

Thanks

Comment: `new ObjectId(hexnumbergoeshere)` is how you do it; what's the error you're getting when you try that?

Comment: I've added the complete router code that I'm using and I'm just getting a 500 error in the node console, so it doesn't even get as far as the console log for an update error.

Comment: What's the value of `thisId` when the error occurs? Aren't you seeing a stack trace in your node console with the error?

Comment: what is the value of `req.body.id`?

Comment: The only output I get in the node console is `POST /edit 500 32.018 ms - 1623` I've tried to see what the value of `thisId` is by logging it to the console, but the code isn't even getting that far. The value of `req.body.id` is `edit_event_57e0ed2a7ab17ea8ccb4f998` and is the id of a form field.

Comment: The current position is that I've put a string together from the incoming data, with match and query separate. It's still not working in the script, but when I log the string to the console and then cut and paste the string in to an update command in the Mongo shell it succeeds! The query now looks like this: `{"_id":ObjectId("57e0ed4b7ab17ea8ccb4f999")},{$set:{"event":"Graduation (BA) xyz 123"}}`

Answer (score 0):

In RoboMongo I tried the code

```
db.getCollection('collectionName').find({"_id" : ObjectId("57e221ea368e723925160807")})
```

and it worked for me

So when you send the match expression from frontend , it should be in the same format.

Comment: I've tried cutting and pasting the query string in to the Mongo shell and it works fine there! The query string currently looks like this: `{"_id":ObjectId("57e0ed4b7ab17ea8ccb4f999")},{$set:{"event":"Graduation (BA)"}}`

Answer (score 0):

Can you do the below change in your code and try.

```
 var match = {_id:ObjectId(theMatch)};
```

Comment: I get `ReferenceError: ObjectId is not defined`

Answer (score 0):

ObjectId is a wrapper and isn't part of javascript, It's used by the  driver which you are relying on to connect to MongoDB. I once tried to see what ObjectId structure was and it turned out the way driver was implementing was simplistic an Object with a str field, so ObjectId("abc") was like

```
{"str":"abc"}
```

you can give it a shot by

```
theMatch = {"str":thisId};
```

As for the problem, I am guessing your `new ObjectId('whatever')` is not working, try to print theMatch on console and see what it prints, most probably you need to check out where your ObjectId is defined, it must be defined with the help of driver extension.